# Not able to install GDB on Fedora

Tags: gdb

How to download and install GDB(GNU Debugger) on Fedora Linux Machine.. I have tried downloading from gnu website 7.1 package, but then it fails during

./configure and then make command...

Please share the source from where i can get information on the same.

Thanks..

Comment: Have you tried installing an rpm from the package manager?  What is the error that you're getting?

Comment: Hi, Please let me know the commands to install gdb.. I have checked the repository but it is not there...

Please tell me command line to check the repository.. 
Else commands to download and install gdb at same.. Hope i am not troubling you, but i have been struggling with this for past 2days.. 
Thanks..

Comment: Are you sure you don't have `gdb` already installed?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to install some development packages with header files needed to build gdb. The exact package list depends on error messages from ./configure and make. Here is installed package list on my system:

```
# rpm -qa "*devel"  
kernel-devel-2.6.23.1-42.fc8  
ncurses-devel-5.6-12.20070812.fc8  
python-devel-2.5.1-15.fc8  
expat-devel-2.0.1-2  
libtirpc-devel-0.1.7-12.fc8  
glibc-devel-2.7-2  
libstdc++-devel-4.1.2-33
```

Try to install all of them with yum.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this tutorial which might be helpful to install gdb.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/gnu_debugger/installing_gdb.htm

But for me the command:

```
yum install gdb
```

works.